# Issues in accessing onedrive business using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am following the steps mentioned in the [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/aad-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online).

I have published the app and got the permission from my Azure administrator.

When I follow the steps mentioned in the "Sign in to onedrive business". I am able to successfully generate the code and token as mentioned in the documentation.  But when I try to follow the Step 3 (Discover the OneDrive for Business resource URI) I am facing issues.

When I try to make a get request as mentioned the documentation (GET https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}), I am getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.office.com as the response.

Where am I going wrong,  whether I need any additional privileges to successfully access the onedrive through graph api.  Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1500) `Discovery API` is deprecated.

Instead of using directly `OneDrive API`, it's recommended to use `Graph API` to access `OneDrive` items.

Resources:

[Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)

[Auth overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/)

[OneDrive file storage API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-concept-overview)

[Working with files in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0)